# Iterator adapter that transforms itself based on unary op provided through lambda

Tags: c++, iterator, std

I know that the standard library has `std::transform` but the problem is that it is really a copy operation filtered through some unary transformer.

What I need is an iterator adapter where I can supply a unary op and every time I increment that iterator using this adapter it will take the element in the current iteration and transform it one-by-one.

I could implement this myself but I was wondering if the standard already has this (I hope it does).

A good use case for this would be if I want to initialize a `std::unordered_set<int>` with only the 1st element of the pair in a `std::map<T, std::pair<int, int>` for every `T`, where I am forwarding the iterator arguments to the `unorderd_set<int>` constructor.
I can't use `std::transform` because it means I already have access to the `unordered_set` which in my case I don't because I'm forwarding it.

Thanks!

Comment: This is what the new ranges library is for.  In the mean time you can use ranges-v3 until your implementation catches up with C++20.

Comment: @NathanOliver Really! ok cool that is awesome I never really got into C++20, I'm barely holding in C++17 but thanks for enlighting me :)

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to initialize the set from iterators and not initialize it empty and then add the elements in the aftermath?

Comment: @n314159 If I'm returning a set from a function I need to define the set it's more convenient to do something like `return {adapting_iter(begin(),unary_op), adapting_iter(end(), unary_op)}` like this I'm using the iterator ctor of `std::set` and not calling `insert()` for every insert. The point is that constructing with iterators is probably faster than first having to construct than initializing the elements one-by-one.

Comment: You can use `transform` with an insertion adapter [std::inserter](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/inserter) but there should be much performance difference with a `for` loop.